# How to count how many times delete_if has acted?

Tags: ruby

I have a code block like this:

```
hash["value"].delete_if{|cell| cell["id"]["name"] == ('foo')}
```

There is a simple way to count how many times the delete_if has actually acted ?

Comment: Check the difference in size or increment a counter.

Comment: Can I increment a counter inside delete_if block ?

Comment: Yes, you can do anything in there. Just define the counter before that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## counter

Since every integer is truthy, you could write :

```
count = 0
hash["value"].delete_if{|cell| cell["id"]["name"] == ('foo') && count += 1}
```

`cell` will be deleted every time `count` is incremented, and `count` is incremented every time `cell["id"]["name"] == ('foo')`.

As an example :

```
count = 0
true  && count += 1
false && count += 1
true  && count += 1
false && count += 1
true  && count += 1

count
# 3
```

## difference

Since `delete_if` is destructive, you can simply compare the size difference before and after the method call.

```
original_size = hash["value"].size
hash["value"].delete_if{|cell| cell["id"]["name"] == ('foo') && count += 1}
original_size - hash["value"].size
```

## partition

If you need not only the number of times `delete_if` has acted, but for which elements, you could use [`partition`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition) :

```
deleted, hash["value"] = hash["value"].partition{|cell| cell["id"]["name"] == ('foo')}
deleted.size
# deleted contains the deleted cells from `hash['value']`
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply